# Why has Fieldtypes disappeared in CP menu?

Tags: control-panel, fieldtype

Why would the Fieldtypes option under Add-ons not be available in the CP in EE 2.1.1?

I've inherited a site, so have no knowledge of a broken update or other such cause.  Matrix seems to be properly installed, is working on the entry page and the site is populating the content properly.

Has anyone seen this before?

Thanks very much,
Doug

Comment: Do you have Super Admin access, or are you using a "Custom" member access group? Do you have any Extension or Accessory that looks bespoke or that could be customising the Admin interface?

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to be helpful. Are you a super admin? Are any menu-editing plugins installed? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, I have super admin access.  There doesn't seem to be any custom ext. or acc., or ext. or acc. that impact the menu.  It seems to be a relatively straight-forward install.  My effort thus far has been to verify Matrix was properly installed. My knowledge of core files is limited, so I cannot tell if a library or component is missing.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up:

Although I had super admin access, permissions/access was limited.

Lessons learned - 1) be aware of sites with multiple super admin groups, and, 2) develop your sites in such a way that a new dev can quickly get up to speed with your implementation.